# How to mask particular field values in mongo collection?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

Is there a way to mask the values in particular fields of collection in mongo db ?

Would want to mask two fields

```
{
 "field1:"value1",
 "field2":"vallue2"
}
```

When this is saved in mongo as collection would want it as

```
{
  "field1:"XXXXX",
  "field2":"XXXXXX"
}
```

but when I retrieve this collection. I should get back proper data i.e if i get value of field1 it should be value1.

For now I've used base64 to encode n keep it. but is there a way to mask the characters ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to store values in the fields in a protected way, that if someone could have access to the fields, wouldn't have access to the proper values.

So what you could do is to encode your values before storing them. And when recovering the values, you would decode them. The keys you will use to encode/decode would have to be kept secret somewhere else.

But keep in mind that the keys could be also stolen...

If the thief knows the algorithm  and have the key, he could decipher your fields.
There's no magic solution.

Comment: What is the best cipher for this though?  Is there a recommended one?

Comment: search for encription algoithms